# SubViewController button click action not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have AViewController and BViewController. when I add BViewController in AViewController as a subView and BViewController has a button. In this time BViewController button not working.

**AViewController.m**

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
BViewController bViewController =  [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BViewController"];
[self.view addSubview:bViewController.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bViewController.view];
```

**BViewController.m**

```
#import "BViewController"

@interface BViewController ()

@end

@implementation BViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    // here buttonAction not working
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
@end
```

Here ButtonAction not working. Thanks for help.

Comment: your button action is linked properly?

Comment: You should also add `bViewController` as childViewController. see [addChildViewController(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434501-addchildviewcontroller)

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes button action linked properly

Comment: As VivekMolkar suggested, to make it work, you have to add `[self addChildViewController:bViewController];` after line `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bViewController.view];` @jalil_cse

Comment: Thanks @trungduc now its work properly.